# VHDL - Resizing port size after computed generic parameter

Tags: syntax, vhdl, fpga

I wish to **resize** an entity **port** after a **generic parameter** in VHDL.

Here's my **entity declaration** :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.math_real.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counter is
generic( 
    ticks   : natural := 10
);
port(
        clk : in  std_logic;
        f_v : in std_logic_vector(natural(FLOOR(LOG2(Real(ticks)))) downto 0); --forced value
        res : in std_logic;
          z : out std_logic_vector(natural(FLOOR(LOG2(Real(ticks)))) downto 0)
);
end counter;
```

More specificly, I want to size **f_v** and **z** after the function nest **natural(FLOOR(LOG2(Real(ticks))))** when instantiating a counter entity.

The code compiles, but when I try to generate a symbol file, I got the following **error messages** :

```
Error (10017): Can't create symbol/include/instantiation/component file for entity "counter" because port "f_v" has an unsupported type    

Error (10017): Can't create symbol/include/instantiation/component file for entity "counter" because port "z" has an unsupported type
```

I am using **Altera Quartus II 9.1 Web Edition**.

How can I get this working?

Comment: Unless I missed a subtlty, this looks like perfectly valid VHDL; I do this kind of thing all the time (compute ports using generics and functions) and it works fine in just about every synthesizer I've encountered. You might get better help if you tell us what tool is giving you this error and provide ALL of the errors you get (this looks like a snippet).

Comment: Usually I use a recursive integer-only log2 that is more synthesizable. This might be what's giving your (unspecified) tool trouble.

Comment: Support for things like REAL in synthesis is a bit patchy but improving. Try (1) a newer version of Quartus, or (2) moving that expression out of the port map, perhaps into the caller, passing "width" in as a generic.

Comment: One further point : using REAL where unnecessary is problematic : a tiny rounding error of 10e-15 can be translated by FLOOR or CEIL into an off-by-1 error as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069229/vhdl-xst-not-synthesizing-correctly - this is NOT a tool bug and could come and go with different tools or versions. Avoiding REAL here might be a good idea...

Comment: I tried your code in Xilinx 10.1 (I don't have license of Altera) and nothing happended. I sure it's tool `bug`, not wrong VHDL syntax any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me using Quartus II 12.1 (full version). You should know right up front that when it comes to VHDL, there's a difference between code that is valid and appears to be synthesizable, and code that your synthesis tool can actually understand. Such problems happen a lot with older tools and when you try to do something in a non-standard way or use features of the language that are not commonly used. In your case the tool is most likely having problems with the `real` type. I would recommend either:

1. Upgrading to the newest version of Quartus II
2. Passing the width of the ports as a generic instead
3. [Using your own log2 function from a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750007/vhdl-use-the-length-of-an-integer-generic-to-determine-number-of-select-lines/12751341#12751341) (this is what I do.)